# Finding view inside an adapter listview by tag from other class

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have a fragment ,which has an adapter with a listview of views. 
Each view has a button that opens a custom dialog with two buttons inside - "yes" / "no". (positive and negative labels).
I'm having trouble implementing the callbacks of those labels' pressings.

In the custom dialog I'm using, I was always sending the TAG of the host fragment, and then doing something like :

```
AlertDialogFragmentCallbacks initiator;
initiator = (AlertDialogFragmentCallbacks) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mInitiatorFragmentTag);
initiator.onAlertDialogPositiveClick(mId, this);
```

it worked good with fragments, but now my initiator is not a fragment, but rather a simple view inside a fragment's adapter.

while debugging, I can see the `mInitiatorFragmentTag` is indeed the view's tag. but how do I find that view using that tag?

Comment: What do you need to do or have access to inside the click handler?

Comment: if the user presses the positive label in the custom dialog, he's being transfered to a new fragment..
At first I thought to implement the click callbacks in the hosting fragment of the adapter, but I need the data that's stored in the view.

Comment: So what you need is data from a view generated for the current item generated by the ListView adapter, and an activity context to perform a fragment transaction?

Comment: yes. And since I have the CustomView(the items' class) class that has all the data of the specific item, and has the buttons that open the dialog in the first place, it seemed logical to implement the dialog's pressing in that very same class . Instead of implementing it in the hosting fragment of the listview and then somehow fetching the right item's data.. The question is whether this is possible..
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dedicated class that handles the clicks.  Pass in its constructor:

- The root of the view hierarchy you will access for the data they contain.
- The activity reference that's hosting the fragment.
- Any additional data items you need to complete the transaction.

For example (I don't have all the details here, so I'm making stuff up):

```
public class MyClickHandler implements WhateverClickInterface {
    private View root;
    private Activity activity;

    public MyClickHandler(View root, Activity activity) {
        this.root = root;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void whateverInterfaceMethod() {
        // Access views for data
        // Use activity to start a fragment transaction
        // Close the dialog
    }
}
```

Then you can register a new instance of this class for every button that would invoke it.

Basically, just make sure your click handler is provided all the relevant data to make the decision about how to proceed.

Comment: Thanks.
However, if I to store the data externally , as you proposed, then why shouldn't I store it inside the hosting fragment of the adapter?
Either put the MyClickHandler as a private inner class of the fragment, or just save the data object as a private member of the fragment and update it through a dedicated function with each button click?

Comment: You could do that too if all your data is easily available from within the fragment.  It's up to you. When you accumulate a lot of inner classes, it makes code difficult to understand, or you might have to do too much work in each click handler to locate the data, and you have to start splitting things up, so it's up to you.

Comment: Thanks. I accpeted the answer. Just wanted to ask though - Using the  'initiator' as I mentioned in my post , is not an option in this case ? It works with fragments

Comment: I'd have to see all the code.  There's not enough here to make a call.  I proposed a generalized solution, but there could be more specific cases that work for you as well.